# C++ memory doesn't get freed for seemingly no reason

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, memory-leaks

I am working on a 3D editor using Qt and OpenGL and encountered a severe "memory leak" for seemingly no reason. I have isolated the issue to a single class, which looks like:

```cpp
template <size_t SIZE>
class GlVoxelChunk {
private:
    gl::FunctionsX *glFuncs; // unmanaged pointer, points to a global variable
    Color data[SIZE * SIZE * SIZE];
    Vec3i pos;
    GLuint glTexture = 0;

    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
    std::vector<GLbyte> colors;
    std::vector<GLuint> elements;
    ...
}

// all chunks are stored like this:
std::map<Vec3i, GlVoxelChunk<16>>
```

The two big memory hogs here are the 3D-array and the vectors containing the data which is uploaded to GL.

When loading a large model and filling these chunks with it, the memory usage goes up to about 3GB. When deleting the model and thus deleting these chunks again, it doesn't go down whatsoever. My first guess was that the chunks never get destroyed, but that's not the case. I:

- instance counted the chunks, the count goes back down to 0 after deleting the model
- created another vector with instance-counted objects, which also all get cleared correctly
- ran my application with memgrind to detect any lost memory, but nothing was found
- checked if the destructors get invoked using gdb and they all do

I don't even manage any memory manually myself, these chunks are all stored in a `std::map`. I can tell with certainty that these vectors are the culprit, because when I simply don't fill them, the memory usage goes down to near-zero when deleting a 3D object. What's even weirder is that if I fill them, **no** memory gets freed at all, not even these 3D-arrays are freed.

At this point, I have no idea what to do. Memgrind is useless if it can't even detect a 3GB memory leak. What else can I do?

Comment: How do you see or measure that it does not get freed?

Comment: If memgrind doesn't detect a memory leak, that suggests that maybe the memory isn't being leaked; rather it might be allocated and never freed, but since somewhere else in the program there is still a pointer to the allocated memory, it doesn't count as a leak because the program still has the ability to free it.  (I most commonly see that behavior in cases where e.g. the program keeps adding new items to a vector or other data structure, but forgets to ever clear the vector or remove the items, so that the vector just keeps getting larger and larger, indefinitely)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX the memory usage displayed in KSysGuard and htop is 3GB.

Comment: Are you using an OS utility that tells you how much memory each application is using? If so, freeing memory inside the application doesn't necessarily return it to the OS. so even without leaks the amount of memory reported by the OS won't necessarily go down. The freed memory is available for re-use within the application.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the vectors get cleared and shrinked to fit their size everytime I create a mesh.

Comment: Note: `shrink_to_fit` is a polite request that the program may ignore if it sees advantages in not shrinking.

Comment: It might be interesting to temporarily modify the code to allocate the vectors on the heap instead, and rather than calling clear() and shrink_to_fit() on them, delete them and allocate new ones, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: You can use "summarize free" and "list free" from https://github.com/vmware/chap to understand what is happening with the free allocations.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I wrapped the vectors in unique pointers and reset them instead of clearing, but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, the memory is being reused when loading another model after deleting the first.

Comment: cool -- next thing to try would be to just allocate several gigabytes of RAM with the new operator, overwrite the contents of the allocated buffer with some arbitrary data (using memset() or whatever) to make sure the requested pages have actually been allocated and not just reserved, then immediately delete[] the buffer, and see if that also permanently increases your app's memory footprint.  If it does, that strongly suggests that the RAM is being retained by your process's runtime memory-management code for rapid re-use.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner there's no mystery here. If you allocate a huge chunk of memory, your programs virtual set size will grow, but the OS won't actually allocate anything. It will only do that lazily when you actually write to those virtual addresses and the OS then gets a page fault to handle - at which point it will allocate memory and back the address with physical pages and update the page tables. When you free the memory, the OS doesn't get involved (usually), the runtime just marks the memory for potential re-use and on new allocations it will return previously allocated memory space.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Take a dive into the Linux mm (memory management) code and the gnu libc++ code, some time and it will all become clear.

Comment: @JesperJuhl agreed, that is the conclusion I am helping the questioner arrive at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the vectors get cleared or when you `delete` something you allocated with `new` etc, the destructors are called and memory is released and available for new uses. But it is not necessarily returned to the OS. Usually the compilers runtime libraries will hold on to the memory and it will be used to satisfy new allocations from the program without having to involve the OS again. This speeds up future allocations.

Comment: You're probably right about that, because when I load in another object after deleting the first,, the memory usage is still 3GB. So the memory which was previously claimed by the application is being reused.

Comment: @J.Schultke Not to sound arrogant or anything, but yes, I *know* that I'm right about that. If you take a look at the libc++ code and the Linux kernel memory management code, you'll see that what I said is correct. The evidence is all out there in the open for you to inspect.

Comment: That really does sound arrogant :)

Comment: @J.Schultke I know. But I don't know how else to phrase it. If you take a dive into the actual code involved you'll see that's just the way it is. I don't know how to convey that without sounding arrogant, so please excuse me. I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Several memory allocators allocate *large* objects directly from the OS and release them directly to the OS. I guess J. Schultke's one does not to this. He could allocate memory from the OS directly if he wants to. (Windows: VirtualAlloc. Linux: mmap)

Comment: @user253751 I never said you couldn't do things differently. I just explained the *usual* behaviour if you don't take any explicit steps to change it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl And I never said you ever said you couldn't do things differently. What a strange thing to comment on.